# How to Implement Stateful Polling SQL Consumer in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I've been reading around the forums and documentation, and I can't seem to find anything related to what I am looking for, which is a huge surprise to me as it would seem to be a common requirement, so I suspect that there is a better way of approaching this.

I have a database, which I want to run a SQL Consumer on, and I want to query only records that have been modified since the last time I queried.

It appears that you cannot parameterise a SQL Consumer query, which would seem to be the first hurdle, and secondly, even if I could parameterise the consumer query, I don't appear to be able to store the result between one query and the next.

My assumption is that I would want to store the highest `dateModified` value, and subsequently query records where the `dateModified` value is strictly greater than the stored value.

(I realise that this is not foolproof, as there could be millisecond issues,  but I can't think of another way of achieving this without changing the application or database.)

The only way I can see of using a SQL Consumer is to store the highest `dateModified` in a custom table in the system database (which I would rather not change) and include some sort of

```
WHERE dateModified > interfaceDataTable.lastDateModified
```

in the SQL Query, and an

```
UPDATE interfaceDataTable SET lastDateModified = :#$latestDateModifiedValue
```

in the onConsume SQL.

However, I'd much rather not make any changes to the source database, as that will have further implications for testing etc.

I have the sense I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: You can still drop into a java class that handles the state and use plain old jdbc to get this done.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks! Can you clarify what you mean? Drop into a java class from where? Within the config of a SQL component, or just by using a bean a consumer?

Comment: Just use a bean consumer. You can store the date watermark in a file if you want. You are describing a ETL task which is why you dont find Camel documentaiton describing what you want to do as Camel is a EIP toolkit. Camel can certainly do ETL but it is so much more than just ETL>

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is currently not supported in camel-sql to have it dynamic parameters, such as calling a java bean method etc.

I have logged a ticket to see if we can implement this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12734